# How to check unused AWS Running instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We trying to find the unused(which is not using long time)running AWS instances, can someone please let me know the way to find the unused AWS running instances. Thank you

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[AWS Trusted Advisor](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awssupport/latest/user/trusted-advisor.html) automtically checks for **Low Utilization Amazon EC2 Instances**:

> Checks the Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (Amazon EC2) instances that were running at any time during the last 14 days and alerts you if the daily CPU utilization was 10% or less and network I/O was 5 MB or less on 4 or more days.

It also provides a list of such instances that you can download. If you want to search instances based on your-own custom under utilization criteria, you would have to create your own custom solution for that.